# Mac OS X - How to monitor a window change event?

Tags: cocoa, window, nsnotificationcenter

I'm developing a Cocoa application that shows a list of opened windows and highlights the current focused one. My problem is that I can't find a system notification to inform my app that the main (aka "focused" or "foreground") window has changed. I tried with:

```
    [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(wsNotificationHook:) name:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification object:nil];
```

but it monitors APPLICATION change: it isn't get fired when a change of window is executed INSIDE the same application (for example, if I pass between two Firefox windows using exposè). Is there a system-wide event that I can monitor to track a change of the main window?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you'll get will probably be the accessibility APIs. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347396/how-can-i-use-cocoas-accessibility-api-to-detect-that-a-window-is-brought-to-fro) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853833/how-can-my-app-detect-a-change-to-another-apps-window) for similar questions with (partial) solutions.