# Detect change in frontmost application in OS X with Python

Tags: python, macos, cocoa, pyobjc

I have created an application using `pyobjc` to monitor the current application I'm using or current URL if Safari/Chrome are being used. I get the frontmost application using:

```
active_app_name = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().frontmostApplication().localizedName()
```

which runs in a loop that retrieves info every second. Nevertheless, this solution seems inefficient, given the fact that I can lose info for over 30 seconds.

I am wondering if there is a solution using events, i.e., have an observer that listens when there is a change in the current frontmost application.

I have found this answer [Mac OS X - How to monitor a window change event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217724/mac-os-x-how-to-monitor-a-window-change-event), but there are two issues: 1. I only need info about the application and not about the specific window, and 2. I have no idea how to translate these messages into Python code.

An AppleScript solution is suitable, given that I could call it from Python using `osascript`.

Thanks!